# Salesforce REST API upsert not updating or inserting a record

Tags: api, rest, salesforce, upsert

I am trying to update and insert Contacts using the external ID and patch method with the REST API.

If I try to use an existing record I just get back the record JSON and nothing gets updated. If I use an none existent external ID I get an error:

```
[
    {
        "errorCode": "NOT_FOUND",
        "message": "The requested resource does not exist"
    }
]
```

Authentication works as I can make GET calls and get back the data fine.
I am not sure where to go from here. Any leads will be appreciated.

[image: Postman screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does connecting user have right to see/edit the `ExternalID__c` and is the field really marked as ext id? What if you'd try to make similar operation in Data Loader or even the REST call in [Workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com/login.php) -> REST API Explorer?

Your request looks OK, you can compare with abomination I made in https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/274696/799. It's for upserting to multiple tables in one all-or-nothing operation, without wasting many API calls.

Comment: Thank You for your comment @eyescream
The field is marked as external ID and also marked as unique. I just tried the workbench and was able to upsert the record from there:

  Salesforce Id Result Status
1 0031j00000b9Qp7AAE Success Updated


How do I make sure the user I am using has access to the external ID?

Comment: I also tried the composite method which I want to eventually use, but I get an error:

errorCode NOT_FOUND
message The requested resource does not exist

There is for sure some permissions issue that I can not figure out as I am not very familiar with Slaesforce.

Comment: Just to clarify when I used the Workbench I provided the SF ID for the upsert. There was no option to provide an external ID. That said when I try to update the contact trough the API using the SF ID the record is not updated and I simply get the data for the original contact returned.

Comment: In SF Setup find the user ADF is using to connect. There will be a Profile field. You need to check that profile -> Object Settings -> Contact and see if all fields you want to use are marked as editable. Something like https://www.tutorialkart.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/profiles-in-salesforce-1-662x1024.png and then https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/servlet/rtaImage?eid=907F0000000YaRD&feoid=Body&refid=0EMF0000000RJc5

Comment: My user is a System Administrator and create, edit, delete are all checked for all objects including account and contact

Comment: I was able to do a patch composite update using the Workbench.
I do exactly the same request from my code and from Postman and I get this response back instead:

batch /services/data/v48.0/composite/batch
sobjects /services/data/v48.0/composite/sobjects
tree /services/data/v48.0/composite/tree

I think I am very close, but still missing something.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing it in action. How do you generate session id ("access token") when logging in via Postman? Using consumer key and secret from a connected app? Maybe the app is configured without full api permissions so the effective access is less than full sysadmin. You have Skype / Google Meet / Zoom / join.me kind of thing we could jump on to? Or edit your question with requests & new screenshots

Comment: I think this doesn't work because I am trying it from localhost and Salesforce doesn't like that. There should be a way to develop on localhost before you push your code to the server.
I have a hangout if you have 5 min to join: https://meet.google.com/uuy-amou-rxu

Comment: You're doing this authentication flow: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_username_password_flow.htm&type=0 (server passes username and password, you don't redirect to SF so user would type password into it and then back to your app like "login with google/linkedin/facebook" you might have seen on other pages). On successful login you should use access_token and instance_url you got back for all next requests. Workbench was silently doing it for you :)

Comment: Huge thanks for figuring this out!!! I needed to use the correct instance_url with my request which turns out is slightly different than my sandbox url.